# Is there a function that can execute a character string?

Tags: r

I wonder if there is a function in R that like this.
For example, the function is `f`. Similar with calculating the mean of vector `c(1,2,3)` using `mean`. But `f` can do this,

```
f("mean")(c(1,2,3)
```

Comment: maybe you could try eval(parse(text="mean(1:3"))

Comment: That's exactly what I need here. Thank you very much!

Comment: Avoid `eval(parse())`. There is usually a much better approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you are looking for `match.fun`:

```
> match.fun("mean")(c(1, 2, 3))
[1] 2
```

This resembles your `f` function more closely than the `eval(parse())` approach discussed in the comments under your question.